# How to stop LateX from rendering math equations outside of $ signs?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write a pdf with formulas for my physics class. After the rendered formula, for example:

```latex
$$hf=E_{m}-E_{n}$$
```

I would like to print the raw latex math notation so that for someone that knows how to write in latex searching this pdf would be very easy because they would have to just go `ctrl+f` and write `hf=E_{m}-E_{n}`. So it would look something like that:

```
* rendered equation * - (hf=E_{m}-E_{n}) - *what it means etc)
```

But when I do that it still tries to render that math in the `()` brackets. How can I stop it from doing so?

As you can see it still tried to render it even tho I'm using `\text`:

[image]

I want it to render it as simply  `hf=E_{m}-E_{n}`

Comment: Try \verb”your equation” or, for displayed equations use the verbatim environment.

Comment: Start with not using `$$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Sorry but I dont see how that can solve my problem. All I want is Latex to not touch something like: `hf=E_{m}-E_{n}` so that it can be search with `ctrl+f` by typing `hf=E_{m}-E_{n}` in `ctrl+f`

Comment: I think what you need are example, `texdoc tcolorbox`, _sec16 Libraries Listings, listingsutf8, and Minted_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it:

```latex
\verb|hf=E_{m}-E_{n}|
```

does the job